# Really weird issue with CodeHS

Tags: python-2.7

I am doing some CodeHS for my computer science class at my school and for some reason my program doesnt meet the criteria of the grader, and maybe someone can assist me.

The autograder is looking for this:

[image]

The things it tests with are here:

[image]

and every result returns a runtime error in the autograder but not in the console.

Heres my code:

```
def get_letter():
    while True:
        letter = str(input("Enter a letter:\n> "))
    if letter.isupper() == True:
        print("Character must be a lowercase letter!")
        continue
    if len(letter) > 1 or len(letter) < 1:
        print("Must be 1 character!")
    elif letter.islower() == True:
        return letter
        break

def get_index():
    while True:
        try:
            index = int(input("Enter an index (-1 to quit):\n> "))
            if index == -1:
                break
            if index > len(word) or index < 0:
                print "Invalid index"
                continue
            if index <= len(word):
                global letter 
                letter = get_letter()
                return index
                break
        except ValueError:
            print "Please enter a number"
            continue



word = input("Enter a word\n> ")
words = list(word)

while True:
    try:
        indexes = get_index()
        splitword = words[:indexes] + [letter] + words[indexes +1:]
        joinedword = ''.join(splitword)
        print joinedword
    except NameError:
        break
```

and here are the instructions:
[image]

The CodeHS lesson is 8.3.8 Word Latter

Comment: please, include your problem/errors description as a text cause it is a text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little too late. I just came up to this question on CodeHS and had trouble myself. But I found it somewhere else, not to CodeHS's requirements so I had to fix it up myself. Here it is all fixed

```
def get_index(Inital_Word1):
    User_Input = int(input("Enter an index (-1 to quit): "))
    DexNav = len(Inital_Word1)
    while User_Input > DexNav  or User_Input<-1:
        print "Invalid index"
        User_Input = input("Enter an index (-1 to quit):")
        DexNav = len(Inital_Word1)
    return User_Input

def get_letter():
    User_Input = input("Enter a letter: ")
    DexNav = len(User_Input)
    while DexNav > 1:
        print "Must be exactly one character!"
        User_Input = input("Enter a letter: ")
        DexNav = len(User_Input)
    while User_Input.isupper():
        print "Character must be a lowercase letter!"
        User_Input = input("Enter a letter: ")
    return User_Input

def replace_at_index(User_Input, num, replacement):
    return User_Input[0:num] + replacement + User_Input[num + 1:]

for i in range(1):
    Inital_Word = input("Enter you inital word here: ")
    Index = get_index(Inital_Word)
    while Index != -1:
        Letter = get_letter()
        Inital_Word = replace_at_index(Inital_Word, Index, Letter)
        print (Inital_Word)
        Index = get_index(Inital_Word)
```